# how to avoid over float of an image in a cell while generating a pdf through itext

Tags: java, pdf-generation, itext

```java
        Image image1 = Image.getInstance(sign);
        image1.scaleAbsolute(150, 40);
        //image1.scaleToFit(750, 50);
        //image1.scalePercent(40f);
        //image1.setScaleToFitLineWhenOverflow(true);
        image1.setScaleToFitLineWhenOverflow(false);
        cell18 = new PdfPCell(image1);
        cell18.setPadding(padding);
        cell18.setColspan(1);
        cell18.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        cell18.setVerticalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_BOTTOM);
        cell18.setBorderWidthLeft(borderWidthZero);
        cell18.setBorderWidthRight(borderWidth);
        cell18.setBorderWidthTop(borderWidthZero);
        cell18.setBorderWidthBottom(borderWidthZero);
        table.addCell(cell18);
        table.completeRow();
```

How to fit an image to a particular cell if image size is grater than the particular cell? can any one please guide me?

Answer (score 2):

PdfPCell has a constructor with an option to fit the image to the cell:

```
cell18 = new PdfPCell(image1, true);
```